# Troubles loading XML into Datagrid with Delete Button functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, file-upload

I'm using xml as a database for a file uploader. I have the files uploading and the xml generated, but I'm having troubles creating and "admin" page where it lists all of the entries into the database and gives the user the option to delete entries, as well as add initials to an entry but that's not what I need help on. I had the XML showing up correctly using  but to create a delete button that functions I realized I would need to use a `<asp:GridView>`.

I'm having troubles getting my XML to even display using the gridView. I think I have functionality of the delete button but cannot test due to this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

admin.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="adminXML" runat="server"  />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

resdat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resdat>
  <entry>
    <date>SomeDate</date>
    <filename>someFile.jpg</filename>
    <filePath>http://google.com</filePath>
    <initials></initials>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <date>11-11-2013</date>
    <filename>owl2.jpg</filename>
    <filePath>http://somewebsite.com/data/owl2.jpg</filePath>
    <initials></initials>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <date>11-11-2013</date>
    <filename>wildtextures-old-paper-texture-3.jpg</filename>
    <filePath>http://somewebsite.com/data/wildtextures-old-paper-texture-3.jpg</filePath>
    <initials></initials>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <date>11-11-2013</date>
    <filename>QwbRElE_.m4a</filename>
    <filePath>http://somewebsite.com/data/QwbRElE_.m4a</filePath>
    <initials></initials>
  </entry>
</resdat>
```

admin.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace fileUploader
{
    public partial class admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDataSource xmlDS = new XmlDataSource();
            xmlDS.EnableCaching = false;
            xmlDS.DataFile = "~/App_Data/resdat.xml";
            xmlDS.TransformFile = "~/App_Data/adminFormat.xslt";
            xmlDS.XPath = "/resdat";
            adminXML.DataSource = xmlDS;
            adminXML.DataBind();
            adminXML.Visible = true;



        }
        private void btn_Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //XmlDocument resdat = new XmlDocument();
            //resdat.Load("~/App_Data/resdat.xml");



            //    resdat.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/resdat.xml"));
        }

    }
}
```

adminFormat.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<!-- This is old code for the <asp:Xml> format -->
    <!--<xsl:template match="/resdat">
        <h3>Entries in XML Database</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>File</td>
            <td>Initials</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="filePath"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="initials"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" value="delete" onClick="btn_Delete" >
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>

                </xsl:attribute>

              </input>
            </td>

          </tr>



        </xsl:for-each>


      </table>
    </xsl:template>-->

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <resdat>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </resdat>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>      
    </entry>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="resdat/entry/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>



  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've hunted all around the net and so far couldn't find any resources that would work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

tl:dr Need to have a delete button next to each "entry" in a table format. Cannot find a good solution for delete button/can't get xml to load into datagrid correctly. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one problem you have is with your xpath expression

```
xmlDS.XPath = "/resdat";
```

This should be an xpath expression to selected the 'rows' of the grid. In your case you want a row for every **entry** element, so it should look like this

```
xmlDS.XPath = "/resdat/entry";
```

In fact, you can get away with commenting out this line, as it will assume the child elements of the root element are the records in this case.

As for doing the "Delete" button, it is worth pointing out that the XmlDataSource control is a read-only data source, so it isn't really intended for an editable GridView. However, if you did want to persevere with it, you would need to specify the columns manually, instead of auto-generating them, and specify a button field to do the delete:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="adminXML" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="adminXML_RowCommand" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="filename" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Del" Text="Delete" />
       </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

Then, in you code behind you would have code to handle the deleting of the row yourself

```
    protected void adminXML_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Del")
        {
            /*
            Do Delete
            */
        }
    }
```

If you look at the properties of the event argument **e** you will see the CommandArgument property is set to the row index of the row to delete.

One thing to bear in mind is that you are doing the data binding on each page load, when in this case you only need to do it when the page is first accessed, but not on a post-back. Also, because you will be responsible for deleting the row out the XML yourself, you will need to re-bind the grid after you do the delete. Therefor your code may look something like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDataSource();
            adminXML.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void adminXML_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Del")
        {
            /*
            Do Delete
            */
            BindDataSource();
        }
    }

    private void BindDataSource()
    {
        XmlDataSource xmlDS = new XmlDataSource();
        xmlDS.EnableCaching = false;
        xmlDS.DataFile = "~/App_Data/resdat.xml";
        xmlDS.TransformFile = "~/App_Data/adminFormat.xslt";
        xmlDS.XPath = "/resdat/entry";
        adminXML.DataSource = xmlDS;
        adminXML.DataBind();
    }
```

Of course, for this to work you would almost certainly have to amend the permissions on the XML document to allow the asp.net user to write with to it. And you would also have to consider what happens if two users tried to amend the XML document at the same time.

Ideally though, you should consider using a SQL data source (Microsoft's SQL Compact, for example), for when you have an editable data source.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm mainly using XML because there will only be at most 3 users for this application. Using SQL is more or less my last choice if I can't get this working. Really just challenging myself to learn more things about working with XML as SQL is pretty easy and I could have finished this project ages ago hehe ;)

Comment: I got it working! Thanks for the quick reply and help. Your answer was very insightful.